# Questions turning into non questions

Tags: discussion

Is there anything that you think should be done with questions like "[How can I change the legend's location in a pgfplot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/how-can-i-change-the-legends-location-in-a-pgfplot)" which turn out to be answered by the questioner and for which the correct response is totally unrelated to the question? Such questions are pretty much useless for archiving purposes — I'm not saying it was a bad question, just a question that won't come in handy for anyone in the future.

I guess I'm largely thinking about editing the title and retagging the question based on the actual answer rather than the original thought behind the question. What do you think?

Comment: Here's another [example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/restating-a-theorem-using-theomac-sty). This seems pretty useless as a question but none of the vote to close options seem right.

Answer (score 4):

I’m all for editing the title and retagging. I can’t cite an example but this is done sometimes on Stack Overflow and I guess it’s the sanest course of action.

Furthermore, it shouldn’t be offensive to the OP, i.e. it’s an acceptable edit.

Comment: +1, but please always leave a comment with the reason for the title change.